# auto-fill browser document height to scroll to any element

Tags: javascript, scroll, window

I have a table of contents which matches headings on a page.

The desired behavior is that when I click on any heading within the TOC the document to scroll such that that heading for the respective TOC click is now in the top left of the browser window.

The issue is that this only works when the document has a full page of content (window height) below the heading I want to scroll to.

- What is the best practice for solving this issue?
- Should I auto-create empty content to make the document larger?
- Can I detect this situation and make the document/viewport height larger?
- Is there a better approach?

Comment: `html {padding-bottom: 100%;}`?

Comment: seems to work! it is a bit ugly for documents that are single page and it mis-conveys the size of the page, but I realize beggars can't be choosers... any ideas on how you might detect this situation in javascript and only apply the padding-bottom: 100% when the heading was clicked and the the padding determined necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet for modern browsers.

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var scrollTop = function (e) {
            if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {;
                document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute('show')).scrollIntoView(true);
            }
            return;
        },
        reSize = function () {
            var s;
            document.body.style.height = '';
            s = document.body.offsetHeight + window.innerHeight - document.body.lastElementChild.offsetHeight;
            if (document.body.style.height < s){
                document.body.style.height = s + 'px';
            }
        };
    reSize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', reSize, false);
    document.getElementById('toc').addEventListener('click', scrollTop, false);
}
```

and CSS + HTML for testing:

```
#toc {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

<ul id="toc">
    <li show="div_1">Header 1</li>
    <li show="div_2">Header 2</li>
    <li show="div_3">Header 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="div_1" class="content">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div_2" class="content">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div_3" class="content">DIV 3</div>
```

A demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4YXa/2/) (not working well at jsFiddle, please rather copy the code and test locally or sth.) Since you didn't provide any code to base on, this snippet is created as short as possible. Please don't pay attention to the HTML and how the click logic is implemented, rather check carefully, how and when the height of the `body` is calculated.

Comment: it's magnificent... I am not worthy, stackoverflow really needs a buy this guy a beer button